# How do I use C++ STL containers in My iPhone App?

Tags: c++, objective-c, standard-library

I'd like to use an STL set in my iPhone app (which is written in Objective-C in XCode).  How do I include set and/or use the standard namespace?

In C++ I'd do this:

```
#include<set>
using namespace std;

// use the set<T> somewhere down here...
```

How can I do this in Objective-C?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just rename your source file so it ends in .mm and it should trigger the Objective-C++ front-end; you can then mix Objective-C and C++ in it.  More information [here](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html).

Comment: this is the right solution, but there are some issues with destructors, exceptions, RAII and memory management that don't really work 100% correctly, so although it's C++ and STL, there are lots of special surprises awaiting the brave souls that try .mm extension :)

Answer (score 1):

STL is not directly supported in objective-C.  There appear to be several projects though that are attempting to port STL to objective-C.  Objectivelib is one such and is available on sourceforge

- http://objectivelib.sourceforge.net/YesOpenStep/index.html