# Objective C with some C++ code won't compile

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gcc, compiler-construction, linker

I have an Objective C project with some C++ code, and sure enough the C++ code won't compile

I understand that the compiler makes assumptions about which language to compile, but I have seen this app running before so I am curious how to make my Xcode 4 run compile this project

ie. This function declaration produces an error as the compiler does not recognize the c++ `std::` syntax

```
 std::string string_with_formatting(const unsigned int value)
 {
```

How do I get around this? What #include or #import should I have

Comment: In XCode3 you used to have to change the ending of your .m file to .mm to get c++  - do you still have to do that?

Comment: what about for .h library files as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Objective-C++ is a superset of C++. You can use C++ in Objective-C++ sources.

1. Make sure the file has `.mm` extension, otherwise it will be treated as Obj-C, not Obj-C++
2. `#include <string>`

Comment: what about for the library files?  I have a .h file causing errors as well and it has objective c and c++ function declarations

Comment: As long as you `#import` that `.h` into `.mm` files your should be fine. If not, tell us what the errors are.

Comment: I get #include <string> no such file or directory, but #include <string.h> gets past that error. but not my other errors

Comment: This happens when you have forgot to rename your source to `.mm`. Did you do that? See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823116/how-do-i-use-c-stl-containers-in-my-iphone-app

Comment: I got linker errors after I got past the other compiler errors

Answer (score 0):

Change that file to `.mm` and also any other that includes that file (or that files accompanying `.h`).

Comment: @RD: No, I'm saying if you have a class divided into to segments: `.h` and `.m`. Change the `.m` to `.mm`. And change any file `.m` that includes the newly changed `.mm` (or the accompanying `.h`) to a `.mm`.

Answer (score -1):

objective C has no concept of std::string.  You need to use something like `NSString`

Comment: @Colin the question clearly says " Objective C project with some C++ code" which means he is using Objective C.

Comment: I'm doing iOS development, which uses Objective C, but this issue shouldn't have anything to do with the iOS SDK

Comment: @RD. NSString is not iOS specific: it is also provided by GNUstep

Comment: I understand that, its the C++ string function that I need to compile